# zip.min.js: How to get the content of one of the zipped files (html file import)

Tags: javascript, html, zip

I have a zip archive containing a text file.
I need to get the text content of this file, so I first import the zip file via html file input element and the unzip it using the [zip.min.js library](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/). The following code returns an array of files inside the archive, but they seem to be Wt instances (not Files or Blobs).

`entries = await model.getEntries(selectedFile, { filenameEncoding });`

[Link to the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-parm-2outz9?file=/demo-read-file.js) - there you can import an archive with a text file inside and get the same result in the browser console.
I believe there must be a way to get the content of the file, but simply can not understand, how.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.